# Meaning of enclosing lexical context when we use arrow function (Lexical this)

Tags: javascript, this

I have a question about `this` in javascript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

When I read this article, it said

> In arrow functions, `this` retains the value of the enclosing lexical context's this. In global code, it will be set to the global object

But for example, the code below

```js
const person = {
  hobby: "loafing around",
  sayHobby: function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`My hobby is ${this.hobby}`);
    }, 100);
  }
};

person.sayHobby()
```

In this example, Arrow function callback in setTimeout was enclosed by setTimeout function. so I think `this` it should be global(window) because setTimeout is defined in gloabal object.

I know my thinking is wrong, but don't know how to understand the meaning of `enclosing lexical context`. Could you please help me to understand this ? How to find lexical context ?

Comment: It scope to the container object, thus on this case to the `person` object.

Comment: "*arrow function was enclosed by setTimeout function*" - no, that's just a function *call* which doesn't change scope. The surrounding scope is that of the `function() {…}` definition. If you call `person.sayHobby`, the `this` value inside the `sayHobby` method (and the arrow functions defined in it) will become `person`.

Comment: @NVRM No, objects don't have scopes.

Comment: setTimeout is a JS method  wich **call an arrow function referenced in the object person**

Comment: @MisterJojo No, what `setTimeout` is doing doesn't affect the arrow function at all.

Comment: @Bergi this is exactly that I wrote

Comment: @MisterJojo What does "*referenced in the object person*" mean?

Comment: thanks guys. But still confusing... I thought that `setTimeout` is defined as `window.setTimeout`. So, if arrow function is called by setTimeout, setTimeout has `this` as global(because it is window.setTImeout), arrow function also has to set `this` as global....

Comment: Ah, Now I realized my bad. I was confused function call and function declaration. So, actually arrow function is delcared inside of the function scope `sayHobby`. `setTimeout` is just call like @Bergi said.

Comment: @Bergi this means that this arrow function "belongs"  to the person object, and therefore the `this` **refers** to it

Comment: @MisterJojo Well but that's wrong. At best, the arrow function "belongs" to `sayHobby`. But really it just uses the same `this` value, and that depends on how `sayHobby` was called.

Comment: Could you guys check me again ?  The reason why arrow function can have `this` as `person`, because function `sayHobby` create its own `this` with `person` object, and arrow function inside of `sayHobby` scope used this `this` of `sayHobby`. Am I correct ?

Comment: @wpark Yes, exactly. If you did `person.sayHobby.call({hobby: 'something else'})`, it would use the different `this` value.

Comment: @Bergi if you want, the arrow function is part of the sayHobby method which itself belongs to the Person object that this refers to, which ultimately means that the arrow function refers to the person object.  (and this  why I put double quotes on the word bellong)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the global scope `this` points to global object (in a browser it will be window).
Now when you call `person.sayHobby()`, `sayHobby` is NOT an arrow function. So this call create a new lexical context where `this` points to whatever to the left of the `.` in `person.sayHobby()` which is the person object.

Next you call `setTimeout` which is equivalent to `window.setTimeout`. The `setTimeout` call will have lexical scope where `this` evaluates to window. But we don't see this because `setTimeout` is an internal browser method. You can't see it's code.

When you call `setTimeout` you pass a function argument. That argument included the lexical context of the caller. So then `setTimeout` calls your arrow function back, it calls it with the lexical context passed in it.

```
// global context
// this evaluates to window. This should output true
console.log('this here evaluates to window: ' + (window === this));
const person = {
  hobby: "loafing around",
  sayHobby: function() {
    // This is a non arrow function. It creates a new lexical context
    // This should also print true
    console.log('this evaluates to the person object used for the call: ' + (this.hobby === 'loafing around'));
    // setTimeout is called without this
    // Any call without this. preceding it assumes that the function is in global object.
    // So this is the same as window.setTimeout
    setTimeout(() => {
      // This is an arrow function. No new scope is created.
      // This should print true 
      console.log('this evaluates to the person object used for the sayHobby call: ' + (this.hobby === 'loafing around'));
      console.log(`My hobby is ${this.hobby}`);
    }, 100);
  }
};

// Calling person.sayHobby will make this evaluate to person inside the sayHobby() call
person.sayHobby();
```

Now let's change the code and have a global function defined in the globalScope

```
// 
function myGlobalFunction(callback) {
    console.log('inside myGlobalFunction this evaluates to window: ' + (window === this));
  callback();
}
// global context
// this evaluates to window. This should output true
console.log('this here evaluates to window: ' + (window === this));
const person = {
  hobby: "loafing around",
  sayHobby: function() {
    // This is a non arrow function. It creates a new lexical context
    // This should also print true
    console.log('this evaluates to the person object used for the call: ' + (this.hobby === 'loafing around'));
    // setTimeout is called without this
    // Any call without this. preceding it assumes that the function is in global object.
    // So this is the same as window.setTimeout
    myGlobalFunction(() => {
      // This is an arrow function. No new scope is created.
      // This should print true 
      console.log('this evaluates to the person object used for the sayHobby call: ' + (this.hobby === 'loafing around'));
      console.log(`My hobby is ${this.hobby}`);
    }, 100);
  }
};

// Calling person.sayHobby will make this evaluate to person inside the sayHobby() call
person.sayHobby();
```

This is basically the same. Inside `myGlobalFunction` the global context is has `this` pointing to `window`. But the `callback` argument includes the context of the caller. So then `callback()` is executed has person as the context.

Comment: Super clear answer, and make me enlightend. Thanks you !

Comment: can u explain why this is not  pointing to windows object inside the setTimeout function when setTimout has this pointing to windows object.Didn't quite understand this line: "that argument included the lexical context of the caller."